# Queue Consumer not starting automatically (third party integration)

Tags: magento2, crontab, magento-cron, cronjobs, message-queue

We are doing PIM integration (Inriver Integration) and as per its working when we trigger a bulk sync from PIM(Inriver) to Magento, PIM(Inriver) calls various Magento APIs in asynchronous way.

So, in order to perform the sync we need to make sure that `async.operations.all` this queue consumer is start.

We have CRONs already configured and rest all the consumers are running. But we are facing an issue that this specific consumer we are not able to run automatically via CRON.

We have already made it's entry in `app\etc\env.php`

`'cron_consumer_runner' => [ 'cron_run' => true, 'max_message' => 0, 'consumers' => [ 'async.operations.all' ] ]`

So, now as it is not running from out of box CRON we have to run it manually, like.

`php bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.operations.all &`

1. Run this command in background
2. Run this command via external CRON

Any idea why is it so and why it is not been picking from Magento's out of the box CRON.

I doubt this is because this process is been triggered by a third party(Inriver in my case) so it expects this process to be running every time. But as Magento runs it on demand this is the reason that Magento CRON is not able to pick this.

Please suggest on the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Try removing that section from your env.php file.  I found that after I removed it from mine and waited a few minutes, cron started a queue consumer for me and the default settings  worked fine.